# Закрыть доступ к скриптам

Tags: .htaccess, безопасность, php

У меня в папке `scripts/` лежат Php скрипты, которые подключаются только инклудами. Как можно закрыть доступ ко всем файлам в папке от посторонних лиц? То есть, чтобы я только мог подключить файл инклудом, а через браузер и прочими методами? никто не мог получить к ним доступ.

Comment: какой веб сервер ? если апач то положите запрещающий .htaccess в директорию с includes

Comment: Апач. А подробнее можно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^scripts/(.+)\.(php|php3|php4|php5) - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

В папку **scripts** положите файл
.htaccess
содержащий строки

```
order deny,allow  
deny from all  
allow from IP1, IP2, IPN
```

где IP1, IP2, IPN адреса вашего сервера 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.1 и тд

Comment: не надо вообще allow

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот к примеру реализация многих фреймворков да и сам пользуюсь, помогает..) Допустим, если все запросы проходят через 1 файл, то в нём можно можно создать константу с document root и всё, а в роутере и т.д просто проверять есть ли константа, если нет, то говорим ошибочку)

*пример*

**index.php**

```
define("MAIN",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/');
include_once (MAIN."core/engine.php");
```

**engine.php** (и во всех других файлах, к которым нужно закрыть прямой доступ, нужно написать в начале файла, следующую строку:)

```
if (!defined('MAIN')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```